# Rails serializer: generate dynamic attributes after fetching data in parallel?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Our serializers fetch data sequentially and it's pretty slow. Several attributes are ActiveRecord associations and they make several DB requests. I want to use `Parallel` to fetch them in parallel and then add them to the serializer as attributes. How would I do this?

E.g. I'm thinking of something like:

```
class TripSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :user, :bike

  def user
    parallel_data()[0]
  end

  def bike
    parallel_data()[1]
  end

  private

  def parallel_data
    @data ||= Parallel.map([-> { object.user }, -> { object.bike }]) { |f| f.call }
  end
end
```

However, this feels like a hack. Is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

> Our serializers fetch data sequentially and it's pretty slow

Your question is about serialization speed increase.

May be it's better to use another serializer instead of Active Model Serializer hack.

For example Fast [JSON API is 25 times faster](https://github.com/Netflix/fast_jsonapi#benchmark-times-for-250-records) than Active Model Serializer.

[Graphiti](https://www.graphiti.dev/guides/) is also useful.